# Appending spaces AND one-word-strings to the end of a string

Tags: c++, string, append

I'm having a problem which seems simple but I just can not get it to work.  I'm using the standard C++ function append() to add BOTH a space, " ", and another one-word-string (str2) to the end of another string (str1)

My code works perfectly fine when I only append one or the other, i.e.:

```
str1.append(" ");
```

or:

```
str1.append(str2);
```

However, when I try to append both in a row as such:

```
str1.append(" ");
str1.append(str2);
```

I immediately get a segmentation error. I am very confused as to how it can handle one append, but not two! Does anyone see a work-around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Works well for me](http://ideone.com/hQtiqA).

Comment: Your program is much bigger than 2 lines.  I bet that `str1` and/or `stri2` are either invalid or corrupted by the time those lines you posted are executed.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -3):

So originally str2 was actually a double that I had stored as a string, which should still work. However for some reason C++ wouldn't use it even though it was a string.  So instead I switched str2 back into a double using stod(str2), and then back into a string again at concatenation as such:

```
str2=stod("stuff");
str1.append(to_string(str2));
```

No idea why this works while the other way doesn't (both methods input a string into append()), but it works!

Comment: This is not an answer.   Code that suddenly "works" when you change benign lines of code indicates memory corruption.  So you really haven't fixed anything.  Whatever bug you had before is more than likely moved to another part of your application.  I suggest you change the code back to the original way and actually fix the problem.

Comment: Please see this example:  http://ideone.com/9K2eT9  You see I get an runitme error.  Now see this example:  http://ideone.com/ks6sXF  No runtime error.   Now let's say my app is much bigger, and I play with the code enough to not get a runtime error *without actually fixing the real problem*, which in this case would be accessing a `delete`d pointer.  That's why your answer is not a valid one -- it doesn't describe the actual reason why your solution "works", thus it isn't a solution.